# Rx GroupBy - How to obtain the grouped values?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, system.reactive

Based on a presentation at React 2014 where 'everything is a stream' and looking at the Reactive Trader source code, I thought I would try to re-work some old code of mine to follow this pattern but I am somewhat stumped.

I have two methods with the following signatures:

```
public static IObservable<OrderDto> GetOrderStream(string name)
public static IObservable<PriceDto> GetPriceStream(string exchange, string security)
```

Both methods use `Observable.Create` to wrap up some events and use `Publish()` and `RefCount()` on the created Observable.

Each OrderDto contains fields for exchange and security. I want to group the orders by Exchange and Security so that I can request pricing info from a separate stream. For my final result I want to print each order along with the current pricing for the exchange/security in the order.

For the orders I have the following:

```
var orders = Observable.Defer(() => GetOrderStream("FNZCTEST"))
                                                .GroupBy(o => new { o.Exchange, o.Security })
                                                .Publish()
                                                .RefCount();
```

If I use:

```
var j = from order in orders
                from o in order
                from price in GetPriceStream(order.Key.Exchange, order.Key.Security).Materialize()
                select new { Order = o, Price = price };

IDisposable disposable = j.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", x.Order, x.Price.HasValue ? x.Price.Value : new PriceDto()));
```

I get the desired output, BUT `GetPriceStream` is called repeatedly for the same Exchange/Security (i.e. not once for each group).

If I change it to

```
var j = from order in orders
        from price in GetPriceStream(order.Key.Exchange, order.Key.Security).Materialize()
        select new { Price = price };

IDisposable disposable = j.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", "", x.Price.HasValue ? x.Price.Value : new PriceDto()));
```

then `GetPriceStream` is called once for each group as I would expect. My problem is - how do I get this desired behaviour and gain access to each OrderDto in the group so that I can output the order and price together.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here that don't make sense to me. I don't understand why you are doing a `.Defer(...)` and why you are doing a `.Publish().RefCount()`.

Also, you are grouping your results and then flattening them. Why not just leave them as they are?

Finally, it appears you're using `.Materialize()` to somehow handle the case when `GetPriceStream` doesn't produce an actual value.

So, given all of that, this seems to be the most likely query you need:

```
var query =
    from order in GetOrderStream("FNZCTEST")
    from price in GetPriceStream(order.Exchange, order.Security)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new PriceDto())
    select new
    {
        Order = order,
        Price = price,
    };

IDisposable disposable =
    query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", x.Order, x.Price));
```

Now, it's also possible that you implementation of `Observable.Create` is also causing you grief. So, if you could it would be great if you could add the implementations at the end of your question.

Comment: I'm using Defer() so that the method runs when subscribed. Publish and RefCount because it might get called in multiple places. The GetOrderStream can return more than one order for a particular exchange/security combination but I only want to get the price information for that combination once from the GetPriceStream, hence the grouping. Materialize() is used because the Create can throw an OnError and I don't want to kill the sequence. I am trying to get my head around Rx but it is a completely new way of thinking which I haven't yet grasped fully. All help appreciated.

Comment: I'd check to see if you need `.Defer()`. The use of `.Publish().RefCount()` is only useful if you want any subsequent subscribers to get a partial stream - the first subscriber gets all values, but subsequent ones only get the yet-to-be-computed values. Don't use `.Materialize()` - try `.Catch(...)` instead - or better yet, write a lamdba that cleans up the exception before it hits your observable stream.